# Escanear documentos con Java

Tags: java, netbeans, scanner

Estoy intentando usar un escáner con CmdTwain y Java para escanear documentos. El problema es que no siempre funciona. El otro problema es que aun con los drivers instalados no funciona en todas las computadoras, aun cuando todas tienen el mismo SO, Windows 10. No se si hay alguna alternativa a CmdTwain o hay algo que haga funcionar el escáner únicamente con Java.

Este es el código que utilizo para escanear:

```
//HOOK para escanear la carpeta activamente sin cuadro de dialogo extra    //SOLO PARA CEDULAS PARA EVITAR CODIGO ILEGIBLE
public void SCANNER() throws IOException 
{     
    cargar = new Thread() 
    {
        final String separador = File.separator;
        final String current = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        private void inicio() 
        {
            String carax="nope";
            String face="";
            for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {                    
                if (x==0)
                {
                    carax="FRONT";face="frontal";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (x==1)
                    {
                        carax="BACK";face="trasera";
                    }
                }  

                try 
                {  
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese la cara "+face+" en el escaner y presione OK.");
                    loadingced(true,"FRONT");
                    String ret="nope";
                    Path myDir = Paths.get(app.folder);
                    String archivo="";
                    try     
                    {       
                        Integer corre=1;
                        Integer front=0;
                        Integer back=0;
                        if (usatwain==true)
                        { 
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entré we");
                            String tmp=current + separador +"CmdTwain\\Scanit.exe /DPI 300 /WH 2.125 3.370 scanner\\DOC.jpg";
                            Process dunno= new ProcessBuilder(current + separador +"CmdTwain\\Scanit.exe","/DPI", "300","/WH","2.125","3.370",current + separador +"scanner\\DOC.jpg").start();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tmp);
                            System.out.println(tmp);
                        }

                        while (corre==1)
                        {
                            WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
                            myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);                               
                            WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();                                
                            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
                            //System.out.println(watckKey);
                            for (WatchEvent event : events) 
                            {   
                                if ((event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) || (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY)) 
                                {
                                    String exten = (event.context().toString()).substring((event.context().toString()).length() - 3);
                                    if ("jpg".equals(exten))
                                    {
                                        //System.out.println("SI AL JPG");
                                        archivo=(event.context().toString());
                                         //System.out.println("LE DA AL ARCHIVO");
                                        loadingced(false,"FRONT");
                                        loading(true);
                                        if (front==0)
                                        {
                                            front=1;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (back==0)
                                            {
                                                back=1;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        subir_fotocedula(archivo,carax);
                                        //dunno.waitFor();
                                        //System.out.println("SUBE FOTO");
                                        loading(false);                                         
                                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Imagen subida correctamente: ", "Subida correcta", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                        ret="OK";
                                        limpiarcedulas(carax);//Limpia todos los campos para evitar retencion de fotos     
                                        corre=0;
                                    }
                                }             
                            }
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El mero Error: " + e.toString());
                    }
                    if ("OK".equals(ret))
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            if ("FRONT".equals(carax))
                            {
                                cargarFotoCedulaFront(1);
                            }
                            if ("BACK".equals(carax))
                            {
                                cargarFotoCedulaBack(1);
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (IOException ex) 
                        {
                            Logger.getLogger(frmInicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    MsgBox("Error: " + e);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            inicio();
        }
    };
    cargar.start();  
}
```

Comment: Algunas alternativas: * [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/)
* [JSane](http://asprise.com/product/jsane/)
* [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) Solamente la última es realmente multiplataforma.